# json_encode() x postman result

Tags: php, json

I get this simple json from my php file and it looks right on the page but when i try the link at postman it comes out with a html error.

Encode php:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
showStudent();

function  showStudent()
{
    global $connect;
    $query = "select * from student";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $temp_array = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ');
    echo json_encode(array("students"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Postman Result(not json):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: try to echo in the while()

Comment: I'm good with that problem now but that's a nice point of check.Thanks @Ruben

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I tell you anything you already know but it doesn't appear your PHP script is running at all.  Instead, you're getting some HTML with some JS in it that (it seems) sets a cookie and then redirects to what I presume is the same URL (byethost7.com/showStudents.php) but with GET parameter "i" set to the value 1.  I'm not sure if Postman will execute (or can be set to execute) JS but your browser will (which I assume is what is displaying the expected result).  I gather that means Apache is configured to serve this page when it doesn't receive the GET parameter, or perhaps you're on a framework that does some session handling?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I see that "i" too but i really don't know why it shows there. The link has no parameters. My page has no JS. I have no framework to handle it. But see, if i try to use the same file in a localhost (wampserver) and test it, it will work fine. Any clue why?

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) Are you hitting your WAMP server with Postman or a browser and 2) Are you using a hosting company for your remote server?

Comment: 1) Good question. Soon as you asked i verified it and yes, both (postman and browser) bring the same right json answer. That's localhost. Just my remote server doesn't seem to give me that right 2) Yes: byethost7.com

Comment: I think you might have to consult with the hosting company to see f they're executing any scripts in front of yours.

Comment: That's probably what's going on. I might do that later. by now, moving to another server solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating charsets, setting headers, including lines in htaccess but nothing did help. I moved my files to another hosting server and then it worked. Something wrong at your hosting server side, that's my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For ability to get same results in Postman - use JSON settings header for sending, not the HTML